# Make a projectile to rotate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in the game that I'm producing, the player can shoot and I'd like to make the projectile rotates continuously when the player shoot it. Each player have an empty gameobject called SpawBala which instantiates the projectile.

I'm using these lines of code to instantiate it, but the rotation is not working:

```
//instantiates the bullet
                 GameObject tiro = Instantiate(projetil, SpawBala.transform.position, SpawBala.transform.rotation);
                 Rigidbody BalaRigid = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

                 if (SpawBala.tag == "Bala1" && gameManager.playerTurn == 1)
                 {
                     BalaRigid.AddForce(Vector3.forward * ProjetilVeloc);
                     BalaRigid.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(Bulletspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
                     gameManager.PontoAcaop1--;
                 }
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: your rotatate code only happens once..  immediately after spawning..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to [`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) only happens exactly **once** and rotates the object about a given amount.

---

Anyway since there is a `Rigidbody` in play you shouldn't set transforms via the `transform` component **at all** because it breaks the physics.

Rather always go through the `Rigidbody` component.

---

I actually would **not** use `AddForce` and for rotation btw [`AddTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) when spawning a bullet. You would have to calculate the required forces depending on the bullet's weight in order to get the desired velocity(s).

Instead rather set a fix initial [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) and for the rotation [`angularVelocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html).

Also note that currently you are always shooting in global World-Space Z direction no matter how your `SpawnBala` object is oriented in space. You should rather use `SpawnBala.transform.forward` as direction vector:

```
BalaRigid.velocity = SpawnBala.transform.forward * ProjetilVeloc;
// Note that your variable names are confusing
// You should probably rename it to BulletRotationSpeed e.g.
BalaRigid.angularVelocity = SpawnBala.transform.right * Bulletspeed;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not so much experient with Unity yet, but I try to do the best that I can. Thank you so much for your help.